# While playing video with HTML5 video player, if user clicks on other link its taking time to load new page

Tags: php, video-streaming, html5-video

I am using following HTML5 code to play video

```
<video class="myvideoplr" autobuffer controls autoplay poster="abc.jpg">
  <source src="play_video.php?link=".$link?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Following is the code which I am using at server side(play_video.php) to push data to video player.

```
ob_get_clean();
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
    $this->start = 0;
    $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
    $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

        $c_start = $this->start;
        $c_end = $this->end;

        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{
            $range = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];

            $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
            exit;
        }
        $this->start = $c_start;
        $this->end = $c_end;
        $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
        fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Length: ".$length);
        header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
    }
```

Everything is working fine. But while video is playing if user clicks on any other link on site, its taking minutes to stop video and load the new page. What can be the issue and how can it be resolved?